# Как избавиться от дублей url категорий woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Проблема. Есть товарная категория WooCommerce, выглядит примерно так

```
сайт/категории/столы-и-стулья/столы/ДЕРЕВЯННЫЕ-СТОЛЫ
```

все ок, НО данная категория доступна и под другими адресами, а именно:

```
сайт/категории/столы-и-стулья/ДЕРЕВЯННЫЕ-СТОЛЫ
сайт/категории/ДЕРЕВЯННЫЕ-СТОЛЫ
```

Получается, что это дубли данной страницы. Как от такого избавиться, чтобы данная станица была доступна только по одному url?

Comment: `Есть товарная категория, лжит они...` – вот это непонятно. Пожалуйста, поправьте ошибки, чтобы текст имел смысл.

Answer (score 1):

[Канонические урлы](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru) помогут избавиться от дублей в ПС.

[Определение из вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_URL)

> Нормализа́ция URL (или канониза́ция URL) — процесс, при котором URL
>   приводится к единообразному виду. Цель процесса нормализации
>   заключается в преобразовании URL в нормализованный или канонический
>   вид, с тем, чтобы определить эквивалентность двух синтаксически
>   различных URL-адресов.[1](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru)
>
> Поисковые системы используют нормализацию URL для того, чтобы снизить
>   индексацию дубликатов страниц и расположить страницы в порядке
>   значимости. Поисковые роботы выполняют нормализацию URL для того,
>   чтобы избежать повторного сканирования ресурса. Браузеры могут
>   выполнять нормализацию, чтобы определить было ли посещение или есть ли
>   страница в кэше

А чтобы их не было изначально - нужно правильно создавать структуру и настраивать ЧПУ.

Comment: @Denis  Предлагаешь скопировать гугловский мануал? :)

Comment: нет, выделить основные моменты из статьи и на статью сослаться, как на источник. Потому что если гугл изменит путь к странице, ссылка станет невалидной, а ответ потеряет ценность.

Comment: @Denis, Там нельзя выделить "основное" - это мануал. Вернее основное я и выделил - это ключевое слово "Канонические урлы". А ссылка - на то, как их правильно делать. А это в каждом случае по-разному. Даже если гугл изменит путь и ВДРУГ не сделает редиректо (что вообще не реально, пока этот механизм, придуманный гуглом работает, но ок, предположим) этим ключём всегда можно воспользоваться. Считаете, что удалив ответ сделаете лучше ТСу и др участникам SO - удаляйте.

Comment: @Denis, да. а представь ответ без ссылки - он станет полезнее? Или будет бесполезный? :)

Comment: В целом мне нравится ваш ответ, потому что вы рассказываете, как правильно делать. (А чем это делать — второстепенный вопрос.) Из мануала от гугла: `В этой статье описано, как использовать канонические URL`. Но там нет определения и не описана суть и смысл канонических урлов. Напишите побольше об этом, ответ станет ещё лучше.

Comment: Если рассказать, что, как и почему нужно делать, то читатель наверняка сам найдёт, *каким инструментом* это делать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо. Однако см."Но там нет определения и не описана суть и смысл канонических урлов". Там это есть. Но это не одно слово. Это фраза после объяснялок: "Чтобы решить эти проблемы, предоставьте Google **канонический URL** ~для идентичного контента, доступного по разным адресам~."  Но эта фраза, без прочтения статьи ничего не даст. Ну и вообще - это веб-термин.

Comment: Ну и вообще - это веб-термин. Всё равно, что на вопрос "как называется эта конструкция" (показывая кусок кода), ответом будет "массив". Нужны ли тут пространные  объяснения или нужнее ссылка на мануалы? Я думаю это не только не нужно, но и можно ввести в залужение личной трактовкой.

Comment: Добавил копипаст из вики. Хотя и не думаю, что от этого ответ станет полезнее.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ создать канонические url в WooCommerce - это использовать плагин [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

На странице настроек категории товара нужно указать канонический url-адрес

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке это `http://millersoils.ru/product-category/automotive/motorsport/gearbox-oil/`

Теперь при обращении к адресам

`http://millersoils.ru/product-category/automotive/motorsport/gearbox-oil/`

`http://millersoils.ru/product-category/motorsport/gearbox-oil/`

`http://millersoils.ru/product-category/gearbox-oil/`

В коде страницы будет генерироваться один и тот же тег с каноническим адресом
`<link rel="canonical" href="http://millersoils.ru/product-category/automotive/motorsport/gearbox-oil/" />`